# Httpd Proxy Server 2.4.33 version Worker name?

Tags: http, proxy, httpserver

I am facing the error during start of the HTTP server. Anyone faces this problem please help me. Error below: 
AH02808: Alert! worker name (http://localhost:8080/demand/ababa-database/browse/downlad/app-type/ababa_add/keyword/) too long; truncated to: http://localhost:8080/demand/ababa-database/browse/downlad/app-type/addlistof_secondary/keyword.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apache takes the proxypass for the worker name. It has a hardcoded limit of 96 characters. The URL will still be fully evaluated, but the worker name is truncated.

It's worth mentionning that if you have 2 different proxypass that get truncated to the same value, they will use the same worker & connection pool, contrary to the regular behavior.

You can read more about the reasons for this patch [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53218). In most cases, I'd say you can ignore the error. Pre 2.4.12, it would have completely failed saying that the worker name is too long.